# Tokbox - connectionDestroyed Event - Delay with networkDisconnected Reason

Tags: events, networking, webhooks, tokbox

Within Tokbox there are four primary events:

```
connectionCreated
connectionDestroyed
streamCreated
streamDestroyed
```

We are monitoring these events on the client (pure JS) and using the webhooks on the server (PHP).

The `connectionDestroyed` event's object contains the "reason" why it was destroyed.

We have noticed that when the reason is `networkDisconnected` we see a delay in its response.

The other events and reasons seem to fire pretty much immediately. But, when the network connection goes down (pulling the ethernet cord or turning off wifi when testing) there seems to be a 5-20 second delay before the webhook acknowledges it.

Does anybody know if this is "typical"? Does Tokbox do this on purpose? Is it maybe giving the connection some time to reconnect so that a little network hiccup doesn't completely shut you down prematurely? Is there a way to change this delay?

If anybody has any insight into this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manik here from TokBox.

When you get the `connectionDestroyed` event with the reason as `networkDisconnected`, it means that there was a network issue and the attempts to reconnect failed. The JS SDK tries to reconnect 5 times over 30 seconds when it detects a loss of connection. This is why you're seeing the delay in receiving the `connectionDestroyed` event.

To know if the JS SDK is trying to reconnect, you can listen for the following events:

```
session.on(
  sessionReconnecting: () => {
    //
  },
  sessionReconnected: () => {
   //
  },
  sessionDisconnected: () => {
    //
  }
);
```

For more information, please see the [Automatic Reconnection](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/connect-session/js/#automatic_reconnection) guide.

Comment: Thank you for confirming our assumptions based on what we were seeing. Based on what you have said, it seems we are doing everything that we can do -- kind of hard to communicate with an online system when you have no connection. Thanks!